# Jira Cloud support for ADFS

Tags: jira

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to login to Jira Cloud (not on-premise!) using ADFS.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/saml-single-sign-on-943953302.html?&_ga=2.24854334.549941114.1531768148-1834457328.1501162022#SAMLsinglesign-on-Supportedidentityproviders

Answer (score 0):

From the [Atlassian Community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Core-questions/Is-it-possible-to-login-to-Jira-Cloud-with-ADFS/qaq-p/265936):

> No, Cloud only has internal or google accounts.